# What is about with \AddtoDoHook of scrbook

Tags: koma-script

he everybody

Ist's possible to use \AddtoDoHook of KOMA-script as in MWE below to implement command upcase of first caracter of each chapter, section, paragraph and so one.

obviously i suppose to implement different command as

```
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}

\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/paragraph}
```

My MWE

```
   \documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
% test_AddtoDoHook_02

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

% 1 in order to capture section name:

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\titredesection}{\@currentheadentry}
\makeatother

% 2 condition to define titlebox  bar ou foo (systematically):
\newcommand{\titretcb}{%
    % Si la subsubsection est «foo», le titre est «bar»:
    \ifthenelse{\equal{foo}{\titredesection}}%
    {\tcbset{title=bar}}%
    % sinon le titre des tcolorbox est «foo»:
    {\tcbset{title=title is systematically foo except for foo !!!}}
}

%my test not OK

\makeatletter
\def\@firstCupcase@i#1#2,{\upcase{#1}#2}
\def\firstCupcase#1{\@firstCupcase@i#1,}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
% 3 use AddtoDoHook in one command for all document in order to control all box:
\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/section}{\aftergroup\titretcb}

\AddtoDoHook{heading/endgroup/paragraph}{\aftergroup\firstCupcase}
\section{foo}

\paragraph{first paragraph}

this is  start of...

\paragraph{second paragarph}

this is  start of... ( here I would like >>This is  start of... )


other start of line ( here I would like >>This is  start of... )


other start of line ( here I would like >>Other is  start of... )

    \begin{tcolorbox}
      There is foo citation
      
      
      title colorbox should be bar.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\section{bar}

    \begin{tcolorbox}
      There is bar citation
    
      title colorbox should be foo. 
    \end{tcolorbox}

\section{egg}

    \begin{tcolorbox}
        There is egg citation
        
        title colorbox should be foo. 
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

More generally I would like command in order to start every start line after white line with first caracter in upcase.

So it's too difficult for me to check every line if the firt caracter is up!!!

could you propose a MWE. (I use lualatex and perhaps it's possible to make program in lua?)